# convert xml document to string using kxml2 library

Tags: java, xml, kxml

I need to convert XML document with kxml2 lib to string.
Here I create the document using kxml:
`org.kxml2.kdom.Document doc = new org.kxml2.kdom.Document();
     org.kxml2.kdom.Element command = doc.createElement("", "parent");
     command.setName("command");
     org.kxml2.kdom.Element text = doc.createElement("", "child");
     text.setName("text");
     KXmlParser parser= new  KXmlParser();
     text.addChild(0, org.kxml2.kdom.Node.TEXT, textmessage);
     command.addChild(0, org.kxml2.kdom.Node.ELEMENT, text);
     doc.addChild(0, org.kxml2.kdom.Node.ELEMENT, command);`

So how can I convert the doc to string? Sample code will be great help. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/kxml2/javadoc/org/kxml2/kdom/Document.html#write%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer%29) of `org.kxml2.kdom.Document` you can use `doc.write(writer)` to serialize your XML document.

Here is an example of how you can acquire a `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer`:
http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xmlpull-website/xmlpull-website-redesign/v1/doc/quick_write.html